# Computing Bounding Sphere after static .OBJ loading with Three.js

Tags: three.js, .obj

I got the following code for loading a simple, non-animated .OBJ with a .MTL into Three.js. It's very simple indeed and works well, but when I add the line with computeBoundingSphere(), it fails with a "TypeError: object.computeBoundingSphere is not a function" :

```
var callbackIrali1 = function ( event ) {

    var object = event.content;
    object.computeBoundingSphere();
    scene.add( object );

};
var loaderIrali1 = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();
loaderIrali1.addEventListener( 'load', callbackIrali1);
loaderIrali1.load( 'models/obj/irali/irali.obj', 'models/obj/irali/irali.mtl' );
```

The issue is, I can't find what type of object might be this event.content returned by the callback, and so I can't find how to apply the computeBoundingSphere() function to it.

Comment: I may try if there is a .geometry or a .mesh property onthe object...

Comment: It would seem it can be an Object3D, I'll try to follow this path...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally found it out by myself :
- The object returned by the Loader is an Object3D,
- Thus, it has 2 children : mesh and materials,
- So you have to find the first child, then extract its geometry, and then compute the bounding sphere.

Which gives the following line :

```
object.children[0].geometry.computeBoundingSphere();
```

Comment: You should mark this is as the answer, this way the question is marked as completed.

Comment: Hi tomdemuyt, I'll do it as soon as possible, but it'll only be tomorrow ^-^ I answered my own question, so I must wait 2 days between answer and completed mark. I learnt that yesterday, when I tried...